# Export jupyter notebook with matplotlib images without inline

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I would like to export a jupyter notebook to html or ipynb to display online (e.g. Github). My notebook produces some images with matplotlib, and I would like a static version of these images to be included. I've seen several examples of this, and they all seem to use the `inline` option:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

I've tested my code with this option and the images are saved fine (either in the exported html or using an online viewer). However, when I use the `ipympl` or `notebook` backends (to keep some interactive features) the images are not saved. Is it possible to include them in the exported html or ipynb?

Comment: I think I once answered a similar question. The idea can be to run the notebook once with `%matplotlib inline`. Then edit the notebook to use `%matplotlib notebook`, but do not rerun it; then save it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest but that just saves the notebook with the images from `inline`, right? I don't expect the interactive capability, but something visually closer to the look of `notebook`. The `inline` images are too small by default, and I wanted to keep the boilerplate code low not to scare away beginners.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from creating larger inline figures before doing the steps from my first comment.